# Radial acceleration of an object that is in ecuador

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

A question which I could not solve.

> The radius of earth is $6.371$ km. The earth is rotating around itself in $24$ hours. Then, calcuate the radial acceleration of an object that is in ecuador.

We know that

$$a_{r} =  \frac{v^{2}}{r}$$

Given values

$$r = 6.371$$

$$a_{rad} = ?$$

$$v = ?$$

According to the solution

- The circumference of earth  $=$ $v$ . period

I cannot apply it because I don't know how to find the velocity ($v$). Could you take a look?

Regards!

Comment: Can someone help, please?

Comment: Radius of earth is $6371km$ no?

Comment: @MyGlasses Absoulety, it's. but It says in ''ecuador''.

Comment: @MyGlasses It says an object that is in ecuador. So, we need to make something different while finding velocity ($v$)

Comment: Ecuador is an example of an object on earth, not matter!

Comment: What's circumference of earth ? Drop dot from radius.

Comment: @MyGlasses That's $40.075$ km.

Comment: So $v=\dfrac{x}{t}$.

Comment: @MyGlasses So we'll use $v = \frac {x}{t}$ to calcuate the velocity?

Comment: Yes.  Drop dot from radius of earth.

Comment: @MyGlasses is $t$ time? Also can you answer it?

Comment: $t=24h$ convert to seconds

Comment: If you answer it, It'd be great. I think I found the velocity from your equation.

Comment: Also what do you mean with $v$?

Comment: Wrong typed $v=\dfrac{x}{t}$. what's your answer now.

Comment: @MyGlasses I didn't get what $x$ means but according to this formula; (the circumference of earth) = $v$ x (period) I'm getting $v \approx 464$

Comment: Circumference of earth it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circumference of earth $x$ is 
$$x=2\pi R=2\pi\times6731km=40030km$$
and $t=24h=24\times60\times60s=86400s$, then 
$$v=\dfrac{x}{t}=463\dfrac{m}{s}$$
and 
$$a=\dfrac{v^2}{R}=3.3\times10^{-2}\dfrac{m}{s^2}$$

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the circumference from the radius you know.  You cover that distance in $24$ hours, so that gives you the speed.  The point of being in Ecuador is that it is close to the equator, so you can use the radius to find the distance traveled in a day.  At other locations you would need to multiply by the cosine of the latitude, but this is (close to) $1$ in Ecuador.

Comment: Could you be more clear? It seems like  $v \approx 464 m/s$

Comment: It says an object that is in ecuador.  So, we need to make something different while finding velocity ($v$)

Comment: You got the right velocity.  What is the problem?  When you compute the acceleration you need to use consistent units.